# AngularJS - ng-options select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have an array like so

```
[
{"id":"+7940","name":"Abkhazia"},
{"id":"+93","name":"Afghanistan"},
{"id":"+355","name":"Albania"},
{"id":"+213","name":"Algeria"}
]
```

etc...

My select looks like this

```
<select ng-model='person.contactCountryCode' 
        ng-options='c.id as c.name + " " + c.id for c in countryCodes'>
        <option value=""> - Code -</option> 
</select>
```

What I am trying to do is display the ID as the selected value rather than the name.

I've tried juggling around with the ng-options but I can't quite seem to get it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `ng-options='c.id as c.id for c in countryCodes'`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/811/

Comment: @Moshe I just want the numbers to be displayed! So if "Abkhazia" is selected it should display "+7940"

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select ng-model="selected" 
          ng-options="c.id for c in person">
        </select>
        <span>{{selected.name}}</span>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {  
    $scope.person = [
      {"id":"+7940","name":"Abkhazia"},
      {"id":"+93","name":"Afghanistan"},
      {"id":"+355","name":"Albania"},
      {"id":"+213","name":"Algeria"}
    ];
});
```

When you select an Id, the corresponding name will be displayed.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/814/